# Loading a DataView into a DataGrid causes ShowDialog to hang?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have this very straightforward code:

```
var xlData = Excel8OleDbHelper.ImportExcelFile(fileName);
var viewModel = new MyViewModel(xlData);

_window = new MyWindow(viewModel);
_window.ShowDialog();
```

The `Excel8OleDbHelper.ImportExcelFile()` method works, I can view the DataTable's content when debugging. The problem is that `_window` simply does not show up and the thread behaves as if it did (i.e. it's waiting for the unshown window to be closed).

If I change the code for this:

```
var viewModel = new MyViewModel(new DataTable());

_window = new MyWindow(viewModel);
_window.ShowDialog();
```

Then the window appears, but then of course with an empty grid.

The XAML for the grid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MyGrid" Margin="4" 
    IsReadOnly="True" SelectionUnit="Cell" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=GridSource}" />
```

And the ViewModel's constructor:

```
public DataView GridSource { get; private set; }
public MyViewModel(DataTable dataSource)
{
    GridSource = dataSource.DefaultView;
}
```

This is my first time using a WPF data grid so maybe I'm doing something wrong here, but I really don't see how something wrong with the grid could prevent the window from showing up at all, without giving me an exception and actually freezing my app.

Any clues? I'll gladly supply more code if anything is missing!

**UPDATE**
Loading an Excel workbook with 116 rows x 47 columns works; the file I need to load has 5,000+ rows x 47 columns - could it be that the WPF DataGrid **requires** paging for larger datasets? The WinForms DataGridView had no issues with it and was much faster, I assumed its WPF counterpart would work in a similar fashion. So the problem was that `ShowDialog` was waiting for the data grid to load the data.  I assumed it was hung because I didn't expect the WPF DataGrid to take over a minute to do what the WinForms DataGridView did instantly.

Comment: does the example work if you comment out ItemsSource binding entirely? I can't come up with any answer, because it seems you're doing everything the way it should be.

Comment: Can you stub out `Excel8OleDbHelper.ImportExcelFile(fileName)` with some low volume canned data ? Just to eliminate the Excel piece from the problem.

Comment: I think loading excel is causing problem here. Change your code, give your view model filename and view model uses excel helper.

Comment: @Gishu I'll try with a different, smaller file, but the exact same code ran flawlessly under WinForms (ok was slightly different, was instantiating a *form* not a *window*), loading the data into a DataGridView. @FaisalHafeez it isn't the ViewModel's responsibility to actually load the file, besides the Excel workbook is long closed at the moment `ShowDialog` gets called... but thanks for your time anyway!

Comment: @Gishu the problem is with the size of the dataset, indeed; see update - I now need to figure out WPF DataGrid paging :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that we have identified that the issue with the volume of the data:

- Do you have row and column virtualization turned on ? You can set EnableRowVirtualization=true on the datagrid
- Are you using auto-sized columns ? Recomputing optimal size for every new row/column can be a perf drag - Try using a fixed column size or a proportional (1*) size. You can try a similar approach with Height for Rows.

Comment: I did have auto-sized columns and rows on - now for this particular feature I was working on it turns out the grid was not an absolute necessity so I replaced it with a couple labels that inform the user about the number of rows and other statistics about the data (lame, I know)... But to satisfy my own curiosity (and because I'll need grids elsewhere!), I'll accept this answer and dig the issue a bit further, but I don't think I can get away with 5000 rows without implementing some paging... I suspect computing row height is the bottleneck in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this. I am not sure this will work or not. I think loading Excel in main is causing problem or deadlocks.

```
var xlData = Excel8OleDbHelper.ImportExcelFile(fileName);
var viewModel = new MyViewModel(fileName);
_window = new MyWindow(viewModel);
_window.ShowDialog();

public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyViewModel(string filename)
    {
        filename = filename;
    }

    private string _filename;

    private DataTable _xlData;
    public DataTable XlData
    {
        return _xlData ?? (_xlData = Excel8OleDbHelper.ImportExcelFile(fileName);
    }
}
```